# How to have DHCP server supply different IP-address depending on which laptop is docked

Tags: linux, debian

I have a docking-station at home which has a wired ethernet connection and its own ethernet-address.
Mostly I connect my work laptop to it but sometimes I connect my personal laptop to it.
My `dhcpd.conf` file has a rule that gives my home laptop a fixed address which is associated with its WiFi ethernet address:

```
host personal-laptop {
  hardware ethernet 01:23:45:67:89:ab;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.9;
}
```

I would like to set up a rule so that when my personal-laptop connects via the docking station, it will still get the fixed IP address, but my work laptop will get a dynamic address (or maybe a different fixed address).

I tried the following which gave me a syntax error:

```
if host-decl-name = "personal-laptop" {
  host personal-laptop {
    hardware ethernet ba:98:76:54:32:10;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.9;
  }
}
```

```
$ dhcpd -t
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 205: right brace expected.
  host
   ^
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 208: expecting a declaration
  }
   ^
```

I considered setting up a `class` but I wasn't sure how to use it:

```
class "dock-personal-laptop" {
  match if host-decl-name = "personal-laptop";
}
```

I'm using isc-dhcp-server v4.4.1 on debian 11.1:
`Linux hostname 5.10.0-8-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) i686 GNU/Linux`

How can I set up dhcpd the way I want?

Comment: Check bios settings for Mac passthru, which would hopefully get you different addresses, if that fails you could manually set differenń Macs on the machines before connecting.

Comment: MacOS netdev is defaulted for privacy.  Turn that off.